# PL011 clear interrupt when interrupt condition is true

Tags: uart, interrupts

PL011 seems to have a level triggered interrupt system, meaning, when certain criteria (e.g. enough space in TX buffer) is true, the interrupt line will be asserted. It is confusing how this interacts the MMIO writes to clear interrupts. What happens when the CPU writes to the UARTICR register to clear the interrupt when the interrupt criteria was met (e.g. enough space in TX buffer)? Would the interrupt become reasserted immediately? if not immediately, then when would it become reasserted? at the next change to the TX queue? at the next change to the watermark threshold?
[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say when you search for ICR or IRQ

Comment: added a clipping from the datasheet. it says the interrupt would be cleared. but because if interrupt condition still holds, when will the interrupt line be reasserted?

Comment: Datasheet for which device?

Comment: Generally the interrupt flag can be implemented as a SR flip/flop. The interrupt source sets it and the write to the reg clears it. If the interrupt source is still active, then it is very likely the flag will be asserted ‘immediately’. Immediately could be one peripheral clock. Depends on the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PrimeCell UART (PL011) Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0183/g/):

> The transmit interrupt is cleared by writing data to the transmit FIFO
> until it becomes greater than the trigger level, **or** by clearing the
> interrupt.

As you can see, there are 2 ways to clear this interrupt.  In normal operation, the act of writing enough data to the FIFO automatically clears the interrupt so that you do not need to do a separate software operation to explicitly clear it.  Enough writes to the `DR` register clears the interrupt, which means you do not also need to write to the `ICR` register.

There is another key piece of information:

> The transmit interrupt is based on a transition **through** a level,
> rather than on the level itself. When the interrupt and the UART is
> enabled before any data is written to the transmit FIFO the interrupt
> is not set. The interrupt is only set, after written data leaves the
> single location of the transmit FIFO and it becomes empty.

Thus, the interrupt is not solely based on the level.

Comment: Thanks. what if the TX queue had 1 character but was already sufficiently empty for the TX interrupt condition (and TX interrupt was asserted) and then an MMIO to clear TX interrupt happens. Then, when the only character in the TX queue is sent, would the TX interrupt be asserted again? although the size changed, it is not a NEW transition through the level.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand: You're welcome.  Since it is not a new transition through the level, the interrupt will not be asserted.

Comment: I confirmed this using litmust tests on the pl011 in rpi4